# How functions operate

Tags: functions

I have a dataset created with SemanticImport assigned to "cofo." Paralleling what Christopher Wolfram did in the LiveStream "Playing With Government Data in the Wolfram Language," I did the following (please excuse my naïveté if I'm not using the Code functionality correctly):

```
RandomSample[cofo, 1000][
ToLowerCase /* TextWords /* Flatten /* DeleteStopwords /* 
WordCloud, "Work Description"]
```

It works fine but I don't know why. In particular, how is it that the string of right composed functions applies to the Random Sample? Random sample is the argument. I also assigned

```
bofo=RandomSample[cofo,100];
bofo[ToLowerCase /* TextWords /* Flatten /* DeleteStopwords /* 
WordCloud, "Work Description"]
```

which also worked. How can the argument (bofo) be in front of the functions?

Mathematica's syntax continuously seems to baffle me.

Comment: what is cofo? can you post a minimal example of your dataset?

Comment: "cofo" is the variable in which I stored a dataset imported via SemanticImport that lists various aspects of City of Los Angeles Department of Building and Safety Certificates of Occupancy (thus "cofo" for Certificates of Occupancy). The variable "cofo" has Dimensions {26277,56}. I'm not sure how to post a dataset sample.

Comment: If it is too big to put in here, use [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `SemanticImport`, you create a `Dataset` type.  (If you look at the `Head` of `bofo` and `cofo`, you will see it is `Dataset`.)  So this is not some kind of reversed syntax.  Datasets allow all kinds of operations similar to SQL queries.  See https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/45-datasets.html

Comment: Thanks. I think I see it there. I'm still struggling with syntax with functions, including pure functions. I get the "slot" concept but certain aspects continue to elude me. The so-called "operator form" is also a bit mysterious. I'm not a programmer by vocation or avocation, so practice is what's needed.

Comment: Roger that, apologies.